# What's a good source to learn about QEMU?

Tags: emulation, processor, qemu

What book or website would you recommend to learn about QEMU?  I'd like to see some usage examples as well as how to use the APIs.

Answer (score 26):

**Best Resources:**

- [Main QEMU Usage Documentation](http://wiki.qemu.org/Manual)
- [Qemu Man Page](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/qemu-manpage.html) - Invaluable resource when working with qemu.
- [Quick Start Guide](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/07/04/setting-up-qemu-kqemu-on-ubuntu-704-feisty/) - Slightly ubuntu/debian specific. Covers KVM.
- [Qemu Networking Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20150912223858/http://www.h7.dion.ne.jp/%7Eqemu-win/HowToNetwork-en.html) - Great resource, super useful.

Have fun qemu's a great tool.

Comment: @JonathanHartley - In future, please check the wayback machine on https://archive.org/ before giving up and deleting links from answers.  And/or google, which found a copy of the man page on its official site when I googled "qemu man page", as the first hit for me (and Qemu isn't something I google regularly.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You are right. Apologies. Thanks for fixing my error.

Answer (score 16):

Some additional resources to understand and get started with the source code:

- http://vmsplice.net/~stefan/qemu-code-overview.pdf
- https://wiki.aalto.fi/download/attachments/41747647/qemu.pdf
- https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix05/tech/freenix/full_papers/bellard/bellard.pdf
- http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ee349/f-2012/lab2/qemu.pdf
- http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/cloudopen-liguori.pdf

Answer (score 8):

**Detailed technical info:**

- http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy428/reading/qemu-internals-slides-may6-2014.pdf
- http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2011-04/pdfhC5rVdz7U8.pdf
  I was not able to find the other chapters
- http://connect.ed-diamond.com/GNU-Linux-Magazine/GLMF-147/Qemu-Visite-au-caeur-de-l-emulateur (French only unfortunately)