# What I need to read/analyze in order to understand how QEMU emulates supported network devices?

Tags: qemu, device, device-emulation, processors

I would like to analyze how QEMU emulates the supported network devices reading the source code. Also I would like to share with me your opinions about what background is needed to understand QEMU's source code. Please suggest to me some good books or online sources for the surrounding topics that one has to learn in order to achieve that(I suppose Device Driver, Processor Specification etc are needed?). Also if you could tell me about the programming level that one should have in C (as the source code is written in C) that would be nice.

I have already looked at the QEMU's web site and what offers mostly refers on how to use QEMU and configure it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For basic introduction to qemu and its networking functionalities:

- [What's a good source to learn about QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155109/whats-a-good-source-to-learn-about-qemu)

To get started with source code

- [original qemu paper](http://www.usenix.org/event/usenix05/tech/freenix/full_papers/bellard/bellard.pdf)
- [qemu-internals](http://gsoc.cat-v.org/people/nwf/paper-strategy-plus.pdf)
- http://www.ecs.syr.edu/faculty/yin/Teaching/TC2010/Proj4.pdf
- https://wiki.aalto.fi/download/attachments/41747647/qemu.pdf